# Convergence of the sequence $x_1 = 1$ and $x_{n+1} = 4 - \frac{1}{x_n}$ for all $n \geq 1$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $x_1 = 1$ and $x_{n+1} = 4 - \frac{1}{x_n}$ for n $\geq 1$. Show that it converges and find its limit.
Is my following proof correct?
$\text{First we claim that } x_n \leq 4, \forall n. \text{ It hold for the base case as } 1 \lt 4. \text{ Now suppose that } x_n \lt 4. \text{ Then } x_{n+1} = 4 - \frac{1}{x_n} \leq 4 - \frac{1}{4}\lt 4 \text{, which shows that the sequence is bounded above. Next note that }1 \lt 4 - \frac{1}{x_n}. \text{ Now suppose } x_n \geq x_{n-1}.\text{ Then } x_{n+1} = 4 - \frac{1}{x_n} \leq 4 - \frac{1}{x_{n-1}} = x_n \text{, which shows that it is also increasing. Therefore it is converging}\\$
$\text{Let } a = \lim x_{n+1} = \lim4 - \frac{1}{x_n}= 4 - \lim\frac{1}{x_n} = 4 - \frac{1}{a}\\ \implies a = 4 - \frac{1}{a}\\\implies a^2 = 4a - 1\\\implies a^2 -4a + 1 = 0\\\text{This works out to be} \frac{4\pm 2 \sqrt{3}}{2} \text{ but we disregard the negative answer.}$

Comment: Hmm why do you put the whole thing in one LaTeX formula? It is generally better to put only math in LaTeX, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the increasing part, you got the inequality wrong way around; it should be $4 - \frac{1}{x_n} \ge 4 - \frac{1}{x_{n-1}}$. Other than that, your method is fine.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that any  sequence that is **increasing** and **bounded above** must converge.

To that end: Already **user21820** points out you have reversed an inequality.

However, let us re-write your final answer by dividing through by $2$ to obtain: $2 \pm \sqrt{3}$.

You say to "disgard the negative answer," but neither of these answers is negative.

That is: $2 + \sqrt{3} > 0$ and $2 - \sqrt{3} > 0$. And so you will need some other way to identify which of these two possibilities is the actual limit, and to provide some justification in that direction.

Only then will your proof be "correct."

Comment: He did prove that it's more than $1$, so that's enough.

Comment: @user21820 Yes: I believe this observation should simply be pointed to in justifying the final choice of root to which the sequence converges. (I think it is also quite possible that "disregard the negative answer" was intended to mean "disregard the answer with a subtraction sign.") The OP asks about correctness of the proof; I think this last bit of clarity would be helpful.

Comment: Certainly, hence my upvote.

Comment: Thanks i didn't realize my mistake.